# Start Mining Operation = null (cannot mine private eth chain)

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, console

not sure if anyone has seen this before: I'm trying to mine a private chain.  For whatever reason, after I was able to mine two blocks, I tried to mine the chain again and I get the following...(below)...any ideas to troubleshoot?  TIA.  JD

```
> miner.start(1)
INFO [07-03|19:18:00] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [07-03|19:18:00] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [07-03|19:18:00] Starting mining operation 
null
> INFO [07-03|19:18:00] Commit new mining work                   number=3 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=104.511µs
```

Comment: It is ok to me, `null` is the result of `miner.start(1)`, I think it is a javascript thing. But the blocks should generated correctly. Check `eth.blockNumber`.

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: Try starting a second node miner, which would mine it, as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What is your geth command used to start your private network?
I also encountered this problem before and fixed it by adding the flag `--dev`, which uses a preconfigured private network.
reference: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

Comment: where do you add --dev ?  the commands i'm using are: geth --datadir ~/.jdchain99 init ~/.jdchain99 and geth --datadir ~/.jdchain99 --port "44444" --networkid 99 console

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: what does your genesis file look like? Maybe it is because you set the mining difficulty too high so you'll have to wait longer. In my case, it started mining after I change the difficulty from 2000000 to 20. I wrote a tutorial about this: https://medium.com/@tina26919742/beginners-guide-to-ethereum-3-explain-the-genesis-file-and-use-it-to-customize-your-blockchain-552eb6265145 Hope you find it useful:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the verbosity of the log to max level i.e 6 by giving this is command line while starting geth `--verbosity 6`. This will give us some clue.
Generally the mining takes time to start because it is required to generate DAG

Answer (score 0):

`miner.start(1)` is return null in some time. But that not mean that mining is not done. Mining process is done based on you system capacity. Also you can check your hash rate using eth.hashrate command in javascript console. Hope it helpful.